# Disable postback of a dynamically created button asp.net

Tags: asp.net, button, dynamic, postback

This is my Page1.aspx code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </asp:Panel>    
</asp:Content>
```

This is my Page1.aspx.cs code

```
public partial class Page1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == true)
        {
            btn_Click(sender, e);
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Dynamic button";
        btn.Click += btn_Click;
        Panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
    }

    void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("../Page2");
    }
}
```

From this code, when "Button1" is clicked it should create a new button "btn" and when "btn" is clicked, it should go to the url in its click function (i.e. btn_Click()). But when I click "Button1" it does not execute "Button1_Click()" but "btn_Click()". What should I do??

Comment: Remove this code `if (IsPostBack == true)
        {
            btn_Click(sender, e);
        }`

Comment: If I remove that, then the event handler of button "btn" doesn't work.

Comment: It would be working as you are getting in `Page_Load` put a break point and check.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier if you add a new button and set `visible` to `true` or `false`?

Comment: @katz is it possible to achieve this without changing the aspx code?? I really want that button to be created only on the click of "Button1". I am developing a website and have done a lot of coding already. If I were to change the aspx code, I would have to make a lot of changes to the .aspx.cs code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (IsPostBack == true)
```

can become

```
if (IsPostBack)
```

Then

```
Response.Redirect("../Page2");
```

can become

```
Response.Redirect("~/Page2");
```

In the aspx check you have:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Moreover you can bind click in code behind (eg OnLoad):

Button1.Click += Button1_Click;

and also unbind:

Button1.Click -= Button1_Click;